# WIPS and IDS vs NDR

Tags: network, ids, intrusion

My organisation has a [Network Detection and Recovery](https://www.gartner.com/reviews/market/network-detection-and-response) (NDR) but does not have an WIPS/ WIDS. Because NDR is usually hooked to the core switch, is this enough to detect and mitigate against threats coming through  the wireless LAN access controller?

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: Is it an option to avoid using WiFi?

Comment: You can avoid wifi by using wired LAN but this traffic won't go through the wireless controller.